# Winpcap, localproxyserver, and redirection problems

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, proxy

I have SSLSTRIP HTTP proxy for educational purpouses which runs on a MITM network. The hosts send me the packets and think I am the gateway, when I receive the packets with winpcap I change their port and the IP for the IP and port of my proxy and send the packet to the network again (this is stupid but is the only method I know for the proxy server to receive the packet, if I dont change the IP dest and port dest for the IP and port of the proxy server the server wont accept connections), when I do this process I lose the dst IP of the victim which points to the real server to patch this I take the victim IP and port number which the victim use in the request and I associate them to the IP of the real server, then when my proxy server responds I take the packet with winpcap and I see the port number of destination and the destination IP if I found it I put the real server IP in the packet and the victim dosent suspect and can receive it, but with this method I create a new fordward rule in an array for each request that the victim does and the connection is very slowly and fails (I am renoving the port all times, if the victim use the same port to other IP server I would generate an error in the connection), do you have better ideas?

The basic i want is to do a kind of NAT: hosts of my network are sending me packets thinking i am the gateway, I catch the packets and redirect them to my localserver (but in this proccess i lost the victim hosts real server IP), when my localserver responds I catch his response and I put in the packet as IP source the real IP of the server (which was pointed by the victim) and then i send the packet to the victim.

The system is incoming: victim -> me -> localserver -> real server -> localserver -> me -> victim

From me to localserver and from localserver to me I use winpcap to send the packets between them.

The connection sometimes works but it goes very slowly and usually fails when it is loading webs, I have to found a better method.

I am trying to do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41eY9ID1ejQ

Please any help will be apreciated

Comment: "_The basic i want is to do a kind of NAT..._" Changing the network addresses _is_ NAT. To do NAT correctly, you _must_ create NAT tables to be able to reverse the translation when packets come back.

Comment: I need to route the hosts packets from winpcap to my proxyserver and from my proxyserver to the hosts, I am not sure if a NAT is what I need, what do you think? How should I create the NAT tables could you help me? In this moment i dont know how to implement a NAT but I will search it, maybe can patch the connections problems from/to proxy server to/from hosts. Thank you for your answer, maybe I have to focus in develop a NAT.

Comment: I have reading about the NAT and it takes for each request a bit of data to do the comenback and it is the same data that i take in my program (which is the src port of the victim, the dst ip, and the src ip) when the packet comeback i search for the dst ip and if it is the same than my src ip then i see the src port i have saved and if it is the same i do the fordward, is this NAT?

Comment: NAT is Network Address Translation. It means that you are replacing network addresses in packets. One form of NAT (NAPT) also replaces transport addresses (ports). There are RFCs which cover all this, and you should read up on them. Just search for `rfc network address trans`.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your answer again. I am already using NAT, but I have a problem and a question that maybe you can answer to me, when a victim sends a request I push_back() a fordward rule in a std::vector which allows the packet to come back, the information that I save in this vector is an structure of [victim src IP, victim src port, victim dst IP] (How NAT says) (the comment continues below)

Comment: okay then I modified the packet and i send it to my localserver, but when the response returns I have to do the come back searching in my std::vector the victim IP and the victim port, and it posibilites to me put the correct real server IP in the response, then I remove the fordward struct from the vector because I dont need it more, rigth? When I remove it I have fordward errors with that port for that victim, I dont know why, Is to save all fordwards rules in the vector and never delete them the solution?

Comment: The NAT table entry must remain up for a conversation. For instance, you want to keep it until a TCP connection is closed. For UDP it is more difficult, and you probably have to keep it for a predetermined time period after you see the last traffic.

Comment: Hello Ron sorry to respond later, I created a hashmap to stock the routes. Each route when is created has a var with the time when was created, and after X time I remove all routes with more time than Y, Do you think this is a good solution? How many time do you think should I use? Regards